# Pandas: List of Column names in a pivot table

Tags: python, pivot, pandas

I got stuck trying to get the resulting names of a `pivot table`. The table printed using `to_string()` looks as below.

I want to create a list with the names of the columns`('a_Zero', 'b_Inst')` I've been looking for a couple of days but I am still stuck trying to do that.

I am using pandas 0.7

```
                            sales             
        finprod              a_Zero       b_Inst
        year month                              
        2012 a_January   3146232.37  13441659.22
              b_February  3335326.18  13493656.53
              c_March     3474579.38  14436167.32
              d_April     3033910.51  14244641.16
              e_May       1403770.07   6757142.50
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

`pivot.columns.tolist()`